# Binding energy $\rm^{212}Pb$-$\rm^{212}Bi$ and $\rm^{228}Ra$-$\rm^{228}Ac$

Tags: energy, nuclear-physics, physical-chemistry, atoms

I'm considering the radioactive series of thorium-232.

[image]

I do not understand the following fact:

[image]

How is it possible that the binding energy decrease in the cases highlighted in red? In fact in both cases we have the same mass number, but one less neutron and an extra proton. For all I know the electrostatic repulsion force should increase. Instead the strong interaction in the case with an extra neutron should guarantee a higher binding energy. I cannot find an explanation.

Comment: The 2012 Atomic Mass Evaluation paper has the latest numbers, which differ from those shown here. See http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1674-1137/41/3/030003/meta for the paper.